# Exchange 2010 junk filter not working

Tags: exchange, outlook, webmail

User report that blocking senders entire domain / single email address not working in Outlook2010. I've checked their filter and the settings look correct. I can still see the email coming into their inbox and not going to Junk folder.

I've logged into webmail and tried blocking my personal email using the junk email folder for the entire hotmail.com domain. It doesn't work and email are still going into my inbox.

I logged onto exchange 2010 and check the hub transport and transport rules, there is no settings related to junk mail.

[image]

I believe we have a TMG / edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out forefront was setting the email headers SCL to -1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there isn't a GPO being set...

Check ALL of the junk mail settings in Outlook, not Exchange.  Exchange doesn't have any settings within the EMC for an individual mailboxes junk mail.

[image]

and:

[image]

Then check and make sure they aren't in your Safe Senders accidentally, and check any rules setup to make sure there isn't a rule triggered that overrides the junk mail settings.

Beyond that there are a few KB articles that may or may not be applicable to you:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2447034

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/872976

Comment: It is set to no automatic filtering but the email address are in blocked senders list so it should go to junk folder. There is nothing in safe senders list. I created a brand new email account to test and it has the same issues. It doesn't have any rules. I'm thinking it might be something in the edgeserver? I've glanced at the group policy and I didn't find anything suspicious. I've checked the specific user mailbox using powershell and junk filter is enabled with the entire hotmail domain blocked. Even if group policy is affecting it, it would not affect webmail when I've outlook closed.

Comment: So, I don't have a way to test this at the moment, but are you only trying to block hotmail at the moment?  I ask because Microsoft is very tricky and protective of its own domains/services (similar to how they handle these in the hosts files).  Meaning I can't say for sure, but I wonder if they simply ignore such requests for their domains.  Are you able to test on the same Mailbox a block of another domain like gmail.com?  Failing that, I suppose you could setup an actual rule that moves all hotmail.com to the Junk Mail folder, but that negates the reasoning behind the junk settings.

Comment: Just tested gmail and it is also getting through. I found out we are using edge/TMG so maybe that is interfering with it. But I don't know enough about that to look into it.

Comment: The only way that would be interfering is if it is rewriting the header info, which is easy enough to confirm by looking at one of the email's headers after it comes through.